# Web Part Error: Sandboxed code execution request failed. Correlation ID: bac5449c-0cc0-c068-607b-423681cbdf49

Tags: sharepoint, web

I faced a issue on a sharepoint site

```
Web Part Error: Sandboxed code execution request failed. Correlation ID: bac5449c-0cc0-c068-607b-423681cbdf49.
```

This issue occurred when I edited a webpart 
I have added many  webpart and no issue.  after  adding more than 7, system displays this error

Please send me solution for the same!

```
[Web Part Error: Sandboxed code execution request failed. Correlation ID: bac5449c-0cc0-c068-607b-423681cbdf49.][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify following things:

1. Check if your sandbox service is started
2. Check if the account running sandbox service has permission on the site collection 
     where you're developing the site.
3. Debug with the user code service process and check if your code is accessing something
     which it is not allowed

and Fix :

In the WebApplication UserPolicy, add  the Service Account used for  ”Microsoft SharePoint Foundation  Sandboxed Code Service”  with “Full Control” rights.